# Refactor reselect selector for better memoization

Tags: javascript, redux, reselect

I'm using Redux.js and reselect library and I'm wondering how the following selector function could be refactored in order to have better memoization. The case is that even if the details of a `citizen` are updated, the total number of citizens, always remain the same. So is there a better way to take the total count only if a new item is added in the store, or an item is removed?

```js
export const getCitizensNumberByContinentSelector = () => {
    let getCountryIdsByContinent = getCountryIdsByContinentSelector();
    let getCityIdsByCountry = getCityIdsByCountrySelector();
    let getCitizenIdsByCity = getCitizenIdsByCitySelector();

    return createSelector(
        (store) => store,
        (store, continentId) => continentId,
        (store, continentId) => {
            let citizensCount = 0;

            let countryIdsByContinent = getCountryIdsByContinent(store, continentId);

            countryIdsByContinent.forEach(countryId => {
                let cityIdsByCountry = getCityIdsByCountry(store, countryId);

                cityIdsByCountry.forEach(cityId => {
                    let citizenIdsByCity = getCitizenIdsByCity(store, cityId);
                    citizensCount += citizenIdsByCity.length;
                });
            });

            return citizensCount;
        }
    );
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    let getCitizensNumberByContinent = getCitizensNumberByContinentSelector();

    return (store, ownProps) {
        return {
            citizensCount: getCitizensNumberByContinent(store, ownProps.continentId)
        };
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: In the example `reselect` will keep memoization as long as you call `getCitizensNumberByContinentSelector` with same `store` and `continentId`. There are a few possible improvements based on how you expect to use the selector. What kind of improvement would you like to achieve?

Comment: @AndreaCarraro Although a part of the `store` is always changing, the `getCountryIdsByContinent`, `getCityIdsByCountry` and `getCitizenIdsByCity` selectors are not affected by the changes and always return cached values. So the whole `getCitizensNumberByContinentSelector` selector is always running even though the result is always the same.

Comment: `getCitizensNumberByContinentSelector` is not a selector but a selector factory. It returns a completely new selector on each call. How does your application use `getCitizensNumberByContinentSelector`? Just a note: using `reselect` selectors in `forEach`loops  with different values won't bring in any benefit since selectors will loose memoization on each loop.

Comment: I know this is a selector factory, I edited the question to include the factory selector usage. And ofcourse you are right about the selectors inside the `forEach` loops. That's why I asked if there is a better way to write this in order to get the length of `citizens` without calculating it every time. Because even if the `name` of a citizen is updated, the total number will always remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe might be addressed by **normalizing your application state differently**.

It looks like your application is **currently storing** citizens information like this:

```
{
    cities: [
        {id: 1, name: 'london', citizens: ['tom', 'mat', 'jim']},
        {id: 2, name: 'madrid', citizens: ['mat', 'jim']},
        {id: 3, name: 'berlin', citizens: ['tom', 'jim']},
    ];
}
```

Following an immutability approach, **`cities` and `cities.citizens` array are both recreated** when a **new user is added/removed** or when a **citizen changes his name**.

Normalizing the state by extracting **citizen data** from **cities list** from, would allow `cities` and `cities.citizens` arrays to be recreated **only when a citizen is actually removed/added/moved**. Any citizen data update would only affect root `citizens` array helping selectors to not loose memoization.

```
{
    citizens: {
        byId: {
            1: {id: 1, name: 'tom'},
            2: {id: 2, name: 'mat'},
            3: {id: 3, name: 'jim'},
        },
        allIds: [1, 2, 3],
    }
    cities: {
        byId: {
            1: {id: 1, name: 'london', citizens: [1, 2, 3]},
            2: {id: 2, name: 'madrid', citizens: [2, 3]},
            3: {id: 3, name: 'berlin', citizens: [1, 3]},
        },
        allIds: [1, 2, 3],
    }
}
```

In this case retrieving citizens id's would be so easy that `reselect` is no more necessary:

```
function getCitizenIdsByCity(store, cityId) {
    return store.cities.byId[cityId].citizens;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My store is normalized. All properties (continents, countries, cities and citizens) are top level. There are also top level properties called `countryIdsByContinent`,  `cityIdsByCountry` and `citizenIdsByCity` that hold only lists of ids. As I mentioned above, the selectors like `getCitizenIdsByCity` are properly memoized. The `getCitizensNumberByContinent` selector has the problem. I guess that the real solution is to create another reducer named `counts`, for example, that will hold only the sizes, and will be updated when adding or removing an item.